# Does PHP's "schemaValidate" function supportDTD parameter entities?

Tags: php, dtd-parsing

I have an XSD (for HTML 4.01, from the usual public source) which includes parameter-entity declarations such as the following:

`<!ENTITY % ContentType      "CDATA" >`

... but when I reference this DTD using PHP-7's `DOMDocument::schemaValidate` function, I seem to get the following error:

`StartTag: invalid element name` 
... followed by the declaration shown above.

This is then followed by the following message, again followed by the declaration:

`Extra content at the end of the document`

Does PHP-7's implementation of DTD schema validation really not support parameter-entity syntax?

*Also note:* My objective is to use this to validate an HTML document, not an XML document. Any comments on this are also requested.

Comment: Also note that my program does include code (from the typical examples) to output LibXML error messages: there were none. All that you see here came from PHP "warnings."

Comment: Additional discovery: when I stumbled upon `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`, the PHP warnings stopped and the two preceding messages were produced (as "fatal errors"), this time with line-numbers that confirm that, yes, it IS referring to the ContentType entity declaration given above.  So,we can now say definitively that this IS, indeed, what it is barfing on. But, why?

Comment: Recognizing that PHP is using "libxml" under the hood, which is also used by many other languages, I am pursuing answers to this question along these lines and will of course report back if I find a solution myself.

Comment: ... I am beginning to be uncomfortably persuaded ... based on https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/parser.c ... that libxml might not be prepared to anticipate the presence of a parameter entity here.  (Based on the one-and-only point in the source code where `StartTag: invalidate element name` appears.)  Other DTD-validation tools seem to have no problem with this syntax.  However, "libxml is firmly destined to be The Devil That I Know™" in this case.